# Passing multiple values through the same feedforward network in tensorflow

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network

I am trying to pass 3 values in the same network at one time, since I need the values of all 3 vectors for calculating the triplet loss. But it gives an error when I pass the second value.

The code snippet is:

```
# runs the siamese network
def forward_prop(x):
    w1 = tf.get_variable("w1", [n1, 2048], initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer()) * 0.01
    b1 = tf.get_variable("b1", [n1, 1], initializer=tf.zeros_initializer())*0.01
    z1 = tf.add(tf.matmul(w1, x), b1)   # n1*2048 x 2048*batch_size = n1*batch_size
    a1 = tf.nn.relu(z1)    # n1*batch_size

    w2 = tf.get_variable("w2", [n2, n1], initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer()) * 0.01
    b2 = tf.get_variable("b2", [n2, 1], initializer=tf.zeros_initializer()) * 0.01
    z2 = tf.add(tf.matmul(w2, a1), b2)   # n2*n1 x n1*batch_size = n2*batch_size
    a2 = tf.nn.relu(z2)    # n2*batch_size

    w3 = tf.get_variable("w3", [n3, n2], initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer()) * 0.01
    b3 = tf.get_variable("b3", [n3, 1], initializer=tf.zeros_initializer()) * 0.01
    z3 = tf.add(tf.matmul(w3, a2), b3)   # n3*n2 x n2*batch_size = n3*batch_size
    a3 = tf.nn.relu(z3)    # n3*batch_size

    w4 = tf.get_variable("w4", [n4, n3], initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer()) * 0.01
    b4 = tf.get_variable("b4", [n4, 1], initializer=tf.zeros_initializer()) * 0.01
    z4 = tf.add(tf.matmul(w4, a3), b4)   # n4*n3 x n3*batch_size = n4*batch_size
    a4 = tf.nn.relu(z4)    # n4*batch_size = 128*batch_size (128 feature vectors for all training examples)

    return a4

def back_prop():
    anchor_embeddings = forward_prop(x1)
    positive_embeddings = forward_prop(x2)
    negative_embeddings = forward_prop(x3)

    # finding sum of squares of distances
    distance_positive = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(anchor_embeddings - positive_embeddings), 0)
    distance_negative = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(anchor_embeddings - negative_embeddings), 0)

    # applying the triplet loss equation
    triplet_loss = tf.maximum(0., distance_positive - distance_negative + margin)
    triplet_loss = tf.reduce_mean(triplet_loss)
    optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate).minimize(triplet_loss)

    with tf.Session as sess:
        sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

        feed_dict = {
        x1: anchors,
        x2: positives,
        x3: negatives
        }

        print("Starting the Siamese network...")
        for epoch in range(total_epochs_net_1):
        for _ in range(len(anchors)):
            _, triplet_loss = sess.run([optimizer, triplet_loss], feed_dict=feed_dict)

        print("Epoch", epoch, "completed out of", total_epochs_net_1)

        saver = tf.train.Saver()
        saver.save(sess, 'face_recognition_model')
```

I am getting error in the following line:

```
positive_embeddings = forward_prop(x2)
```

The tf.get_variable in the forward_prop() function throws the error.

The error says:

```
ValueError: Variable w1 already exists, disallowed. Did you mean to set reuse=True or reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE in VarScope?
```

I think it's because the variable w1 gets defined in the first call of forward_prop() function in the following line:

```
anchor_embeddings = forward_prop(x1)
```

How to resolve this? I cannot pass the three values separately since i will need all the three values for computing the triplet loss. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're misconfiguring your network here:

```
def back_prop():
    anchor_embeddings = forward_prop(x1)
    positive_embeddings = forward_prop(x2)
    negative_embeddings = forward_prop(x3)
```

You should only define 1 network, you're erroneously defining 3 sets of variables for each of the 3 inputs, effectively 3 neural networks are being defined here.

For triplet loss what you want to do is feed the 3 inputs in as a batch to a single network (all 3 get processed by the same network), not as individual variables. For this discussion, I'll assume your inputs are images and you're training on a single set of 3 inputs on each training step.

If your images are 256x256x1 (grayscale) in size, then a single triplet batch would be of shape [3 x 256 x 256 x 1]. Now your output will be of shape [3 x size_of_your_output_layer]. Your loss function should now be written with the understanding that the first axis there represents your 3 values: anchor, positive, negative. Compute the loss appropriately.

You can, of course, pass in multiple anchors, positives, and negatives, you'll just have to deal with this in more complex detail at the loss function, perfectly doable though. My triplet loss functions have gotten pretty complex though, so I suggest keeping it simple to start.